# Passing Array to a function gives an error in function prototype declaration

Tags: c++

i am learning c++ and get in a problem in "passing array to a function "
the IDE gives compile error.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray{int theArray[], int sizeOfArray};

int main()
{
int kartik[5] = {22, 43, 65, 43, 54};
int awasthi[2] = {11,43};

printArray(kartik , 5);
}

void printArray{int theArray[], int sizeOfArray}{
for(x=0; x<sizeOfArray, x++){
    cout << theArray[x] <<endl;
 }

 }
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried. It's next to impossible to guess what your mistake might have been without more information.

Comment: Showing your code would be a good first step.

Comment: Show your code and error

Comment: Should I learn psychic abilities before I help you out with your `code`?

Comment: @N.Ivanov. You already know the answer, surely?

Comment: Have you reviewed your C++ reference or text book on passing arrays?

Comment: If you are allowed to use `std::vector`, you should.  It's easier to pass to functions.

Comment: Please don't add phrases like "it's urgent!" or "please help me as soon as possible" to your questions - it's perceived as demanding. It also makes it sound like you think that your question is more important than everyone else's (which it's not). *Everyone* wants a quick answer to their questions, not just you.

Comment: Start by fixing the simple errors (such as the use of `x` which is never defined).  Then ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your for loop. The variable `x` need to be initialized first.

The syntax is

```
for(initialization; condition ; increment/decrement)
{
   C++ statement(s);
}
```

Your condition is ending with a comma (`,`).

```
for(int x=0; x<sizeOfArray; x++){
    cout << theArray[x] <<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In printArray function, you have not decleared what x is. First decleare int x; or put int before x in for loop. And next time please put what error is.

Edit: and change comma with ';' in for loop.